# How to update date in ms access through netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, sqlexception

*Exception : *

```
       java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in       UPDATE statement
```

*code is:*

```
    String Name = txtName.getText();`
    String Email = txtEmail.getText();
    String Mobile = txtMobile.getText();
    String Address = txtAddress.getText();
    String Dob = txtDob.getText();
```

try
                 {

```
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:NewPData");
            String query = "update Table1 set Name='" + Name + "' , Email='" + Email + "' , Mobile=" + Mobile + ", Address= '" + Address
```

+ "', DOB=" +Dob + ", where ID=" + Update;
                PreparedStatement ps_Statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                ps_Statement.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panelID, "Record Updated Successfully");
                connection.close();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

Answer (score 0):

You have a , before the where clause. And DOB if it is a date should come within single quotes. And are you sure Mobile is a integer?

```
"update Table1 set Name='" + Name + "' , Email='" + Email + "' , Mobile=" + Mobile + ", Address= '" + Address
+ "', DOB='" +Dob + "' where ID=" + Update;
```

But anyway consider using PreparedStatement with argument passing. The SQL you are using is vulnerable for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: yes mobile in an integer so i didn't put single quotes....for date of birth i have also put single quotes but got the same exception

Comment: can you put a line to print query variable to console and paste the SQL generated? System.out.println(query);

Comment: i dont understand what are you talking about?? and ya in mobile case i got the same error coz i was not putting single quotes ...so i think there is a problem in my query..i have also put #Dob# but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Please try this instead:

```
String yourFormat = "dd-MMM-yy";
Date yourDateVariable = null;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(yourFormat);

try {
    yourDateVariable = sdf.parse(Dob);
} catch ( Exception ex ) {
    // Do something
}

// Continue your code<code>
```

Comment: problem is not because of mobile it is because of date..      i have already converted mobile to integer same as u wrote

Comment: I'm very sorry, I never thought some variable was actually has to be a Date. IN that case, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: michael can i convert that string to a date and then try to update??

Comment: Yes, SimpleDateFormat.parse will actually convert your String datatype to a Date datatype.

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ?

Comment: Try in this format 'EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy' it might be the format.