# JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog not working in netbeans when i retrive some data to show on dialogue box

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc

Here is code:

```
       int value = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(Delete_Panel, "Delete Record of '"+rs.getString("Name")+"'", "Delete Now", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

It does nothing .. 
but when I remove `rs.getString("Name")` it works perfectly but I also want to show that name from ms access on confirm dialogue and then according to yes no option I want my further code to be executed.

Full Source code is:

```
       String input = txtDelete.getText();


        Connection connection;

        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:NewPData");
            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select ID from Table1 where ID=" + input);

            if (!rs.next()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Delete_Panel, "ID does not exist");
            } else {

             // int value = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(Delete_Panel, "Delete Record of '"+rs.getString("Name")+"'", "Delete Now", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                st.executeUpdate("delete from Table1 where ID=" + input);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Delete_Panel, "Record is Deleted");
                connection.close();

            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work just fine. Please post what was the exact output in the dialog.

Have you tried to fetch the data first before invoking the showConfirmDialog?

rs = Statement.executeQuery

EDIT:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select ID from Table1 where ID=" + input);
```

Will only get the colum ID. Try this:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select ID,Name from Table1 where ID=" + input);
```

Comment: Your rs might be null. Try to execute the query first before showing the confirmation dialog.

Comment: yes i think u guys r right rs getting a null value how do i solve it?

Comment: hey try dis question also:     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699162/how-to-update-date-in-ms-access-through-netbeans

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the code in a try-catch block and see if an exception is raised. If yes, then you'll have to handle it in order to get some text in the UI.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Column not found

Comment: Thats it then, the column that you are using i.e. "Name" is not the name of a column in the result that you are getting. Check the name of this column, upper case / lower case and you should be able to figure out the problem.

Comment: If rs.getString("Name") is giving a null value, then you should use a temporary variable and act accordingly. For example String temp =  rs.getString("Name"); if(null==temp){temp = "No Name Found";} and use this temp instead of  rs.getString("Name") in your code.

Comment: thnx dude my problem is solved u can see the right ans :) thnx amit

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about creating a temporary String variable, and setting it to the output of `rs.getString("Name")`, then displaying that String inside of the JOptionPane?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah as said in earlier answer, it may be the case that rs is empty or rs.next() has been never called or there is no column "name" in the resultset and hence we are trying to concatenate null name. Is there any exception while doing this.? Better take this rs.getString("Name") value in temporary variable and see is it really a non null value. That's the only problem I can see.

Comment: yes i think u guys r right rs getting a null value how do i solve it?